# OnNestedPreScroll returns opposite values of dy in custom Behavior class

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, behavior

Have an issue. In my custom Behaviour class which i set to custom view. I track moves of recycler view and get all offsets in Behavior Class methods. onNestedScroll, onNestedPreScroll and after that change the size of my view. And when my view is expanded and i try to collapse it i get opposite values of dy in onNestedPreScroll method like: 40 -50 120 -130 300 -320 etc. but i move finger only in one direction.
Search all over the Web. Didn't ffind anything. Could you help me?

```
class CustomFilterBehavior : CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<CustomFilterViewTabLayout> {
private var skipNestedPreScroll = false

constructor(context: Context) : this(context, null)
constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)

override fun onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout,
                               child: CustomFilterViewTabLayout,
                               directTargetChild: View,
                               target: View?,
                               nestedScrollAxes: Int): Boolean {


 return nestedScrollAxes and ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL != 0
}

override fun onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout?,
                          child: CustomFilterViewTabLayout?,
                          target: View?,
                          dxConsumed: Int,
                          dyConsumed: Int,
                          dxUnconsumed: Int,
                          dyUnconsumed: Int) {
 if (dyUnconsumed < 0) {
   child?.moveLayout(dyUnconsumed, false)
   skipNestedPreScroll = true
 } else {
   skipNestedPreScroll = false
 }
}

override fun onNestedPreScroll(coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout?, child: CustomFilterViewTabLayout?, target: View?, dx: Int, dy: Int, consumed: IntArray?) {
  if (dy != 0 && !skipNestedPreScroll) {
    child?.let {
      println(dy)
      consumed?.set(1, it.moveLayout(dy, true))
  }
 }
}

override fun onStopNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout?,
                              child: CustomFilterViewTabLayout?,
                              target: View?) {
  child?.stopScroll()
  skipNestedPreScroll = false
  super.onStopNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target)
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you found the solution? I met the same issue

Comment: Did you find solution? When recyclerview item set onClickListener, dy is opposite, otherwise it works seems right.

Comment: I'm currently running with the same issue as you faced. Let us know if you find any solutions. Thanks.

Comment: No, I haven't found any possible solution...